# Как установить точку поворота при использовании CSS анимации

Tags: css, svg, css-animation

Как установить точку поворота по центру при использовании CSS анимации?

`transform-origin: center center;` не помогает

```html
<svg xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
          xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
          baseProfile="full" height="100%" version="1.1" 
          viewBox="0 0 1024 768" width="100%">
     <defs>
      <style type="text/css">
       @keyframes rotate {
        0% {transform: rotate(0deg); transform-origin: center center;}
        100% {transform: rotate(360deg); transform-origin: center center;}
    
        0% {fill: #ffff00;}
        50% {fill: #ff0000;}
        100% {fill: #ffff00;}
       }
       .d {
        animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
       }
      </style>
     </defs>
      <rect x="250" y="250" width="100" height="100" class="d"/>
    </svg>
```

Comment: .d {transform-box: fill-box}

Comment: @hu-fo, благодарю. Проблема решена.

Comment: @ioprst Хорошо бы вам самому оформить ответ. Комментарии редко кто читает. А так вопрос есть, ответа нет. Немного и репы заработаете и вопрос не останется висеть не отвеченным.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Та же самая анимация, но в SVG.

```html
<svg  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
           height="100%" width="100%"  
          viewBox="0 0 1024 768" >
     
      <rect x="250" y="250" width="100" height="100" class="d" fill="#ffff00">
     <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="0s" dur="1s" values="0 300 300;360 300 300" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    <animate attributeName="fill" begin="0s" dur="1s" values="#ffff00;#ff0000;#ffff00" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </rect> 
    </svg>
```

Comment: спасибо. Считается ли допустимым (по "канону") добавлять в элементы анимацию с помощью innerHTML для обновления SVG в режиме реального времени? Или лучше использовать CSS?

Comment: @ioprst SVG Прекрасно  взаимодействует с CSS+JS. Как внутри файла SVG, так и извне. Только нужно учитывать,  что CSS может анимировать не все атрибуты SVG элементов.  JS может всё, как полностью создать с нуля SVG элемент и его анимацию, так и частично, - управляя анимацией SVG

Answer (score 5):

Необходимо для класса `d` добавить свойство `transform-box` со значением `fill-box`.
<sub>[комментарий @hu-fo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1071949/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-css-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8/1072097#comment1839651_1071949)</sub>

Результат:

```html
<svg xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
          xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
          baseProfile="full" height="100%" version="1.1" 
          viewBox="0 0 1024 768" width="100%">
     <defs>
      <style type="text/css">
       @keyframes rotate {
        0% {transform: rotate(0deg); transform-origin: center center;}
        100% {transform: rotate(360deg); transform-origin: center center;}
    
        0% {fill: #ffff00;}
        50% {fill: #ff0000;}
        100% {fill: #ffff00;}
       }
       .d {
        transform-box: fill-box;
        animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
       }
      </style>
     </defs>
      <rect x="250" y="250" width="100" height="100" class="d"/>
    </svg>
```